# Rails associations - NoMethodError: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on project with associations between Invoices and Vat (both models). Every time I try to get a value of the Vat through the console like @Invoice.last.vat.amount I get the message **Rails associations - NoMethodError: undefined method**

I *think* I have the migrations done correctly but somehow I'm overlooking something:

My models:

```
class Vat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vats
  belongs_to :client
end
```

My migrations:

For **Invoices**

```
class CreateInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invoices do |t|
      t.datetime :issue_time
      t.integer :total
      t.integer :vat
      t.string :item
      t.string :currency
      t.references :client, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

For **Vat**

```
class CreateVats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :vats do |t|
      t.integer :amount
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And a later modification to add **Vat** to **Invoices**:

```
class AddVatToInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :invoices, :vat, index: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, however

1) You set your Invoice has_many vats, means you need to call vats, i.e. `Invoice.last.vats`

2) I have not seen amount, but I know count. So you want to do `Invoice.last.vats.count`.

Enjoy!

Comment: No - Vats, in plural is needed for the migration. And if I do Invoice.last.vat I get the VAT ID correct, but not the amount of the Vat it self which is a column in the Vat table.

Comment: Are you sure you want amount? I can see count in my rails c. Amount throws error message.